# Angular life-cycle hook when parsing large quantity of Json

Tags: json, angular, parsing, html-parsing

I am using Angular to query a java backend that returns 1000 json objects, these then get parsed into a HTML table:

```
<tr class="businessItemList" *ngFor="let x of businessItemsInitialSearchResults">
    <td *ngFor="let y of headingsBeingDisplayed">
      <a [routerLink]="['/businessItem', x.uniqueNumber]">{{x[y.propertyName]}}</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
```

My question is, I want to show a loading wheel when the user does a search and have this disappear when the Json is returned and is parsed into the table - the query returns pretty quickly but as there is a lot of parsing Json the UI is not fully updated for 5+ seconds afterward. How can I be notified when the UI completes so I can then hide the loading wheel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create service for show and hide loading spiral like:

```
@Injectable()
export class ShareService {
    isLoading:boolean;
    showLoader(){
        return this.isLoading=true;
    }
    hideLoader(){
        return this.isLoading=false;
    }
}
```

now you can use this service in your component where you call in your function like:

```
loadData(){  
    this.isLoading = this.shareService.showLoader();
    this.dataService.getAllData()
        .subscribe(
            news=>{
              this.data=data;               
              this.isLoading = this.shareService.hideLoader();
            },err=>{
              alert("Something went wrong");
              this.isLoading = this.shareService.hideLoader();
            }
        )
  }
```

In your HTML file add

```
<div id="loader" *ngIf="isLoading"></div>
```

add css for loader id

Answer (score 0):

Compare index and length of businessItemsInitialSearchResults as

```
<div ng-if="(businessItemsInitialSearchResults.length-1) != $index"> 
    <img src="../Images/load.gif" style="width:359px;height:349px;align-content:center" /> 
</div>
```